# Count Images in a Div

Tags: jquery, css, image

I'm having issues count the number of images in a div.

For example 1/4, 2/4, 3/4, 4/4

This the small code I am trying to figuring out

```
//count image
var currentNum = $(this).iniShow() + 1;
var count = $(this).closest('.slideshow').find('img:first').length;
var item = $(this).closest('.slideshow').attr('id');
       $('.' + item ).html(currentNum + ' of ' + count);
```

Here is my html code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">   </script>
</head>
<style>
.slideshow img { display: none; cursor: pointer; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
//previous slide
$('.slideshow .prev').click(function() {
    prevSlide($(this).closest('.slideshow').find('.slides'));
});
//next slide
$('.slideshow .next, .slideshow img,').click(function() {
    nextSlide($(this).closest('.slideshow').find('.slides'));
});
//initialize show
iniShow();
function iniShow() {
    // show first slide with caption
    $('.slideshow').each(function() {
        showSlide($(this).find('.slides'));
    });
}
// move previous slide 
function prevSlide($slides) {
    $slides.find('img:last').prependTo($slides);
    showSlide($slides);
}
// move next slide 
function nextSlide($slides) {
    $slides.find('img:first').appendTo($slides);
    showSlide($slides);
}
// show slide with caption
function showSlide($slides) {
    var $nextSlide = $slides.find('img:first');
    //hide (reset) all slides
    $slides.find('img').hide();
    //fade in next slide
    $nextSlide.fadeIn(500);
    //show caption
    $('#caption').text($nextSlide[0].alt);
    //count image
    var currentNum = $(this).iniShow() + 1;
    var count = $(this).closest('.slideshow').find('img').length;
    $('#count').html(currentNum + ' of ' + count);
    }
});
</script>
<body>
<div class="slideshow">
<div class="slides">
    <img src="image/1a.jpg" width="500" height="500" alt="Caption 1 Image is ..." />
    <img src="image/2a.jpg" width="500" height="500" alt="Caption 2 Image is ..." />
    <img src="image/3a.jpg" width="500" height="500" alt="Caption 3 Image is ..." />
    <img src="image/4a.jpg" width="500" height="500" alt="Caption 4 Image is ..." />
</div>
<p id="caption"></p> / <p id="count"></p>
<div class="controls">
<a class="prev" href="javascript:void(0);">Previous</a> -
<a class="next" href="javascript:void(0);">Next</a>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated. I also want to know am I close to solve this issue. Thanks.

Comment: you're using `:first`, the count will always be 0 or 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use count as selector. [changes in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xYXGX/2/)

for

```
var item = $(this).closest('.slideshow').attr('id');
       $('.' + item ).html(currentNum + ' of ' + count);
```

I believe you want to show your count in div with id `count`. for id you should use # instead of .(which used for class selectopr).

```
   $('#count').html(currentNum + ' of ' + count);
```

Modified code:

```
var currentNum = $(this).iniShow() + 1;
var count = $(this).closest('.slideshow').find('img').length;
       $('#count').html(currentNum + ' of ' + count);
```

Comment: @Shusl, Thanks for the reply and example I will make some adjustments

Comment: @Shusl, I made some adjustments. It didn't work. The count didn't appear. I try to change the slideshow & slides from class to id. Then all 4 images appear at once. When I used class again. it went back to normal. But the count doesn't appear

Comment: on which event you setting the count. when you are setting the count?

Comment: @LightM1 I got it you were using iniShow method which not present hence stopping futher exection

Comment: @Shusl correct I used inishow to start the image when I set the count it's this img:first so it is 1 not 0. I think there was another member it should be 0 not 1 so I'm a bit confused with that I always assume it starts at 1 because it's the first image

Comment: Do I need to change the inishow? Without it the whole script won't work

Comment: I will make some adjustment on my example above base on your suggestion and changes

Comment: @LightM1 give me some time there are many problems I am looking into it.

Comment: @LightM1 I made some changes in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xYXGX/ it  is working now. but there is a problem since you are shuffling the images it is hard to find index of image so it always showing as 1 of 4 . is there any information for index of image means are you storing any information about image initial position?

Comment: @Shusl all of the caption is in the alt so there's no information about the initial position

Comment: @Shusl It does look weird. Does it count the images in the div? it look like it does I think

Comment: @Shusl  I already test it out on my side no it doesn't count. I try to change the $nextSlide to just $slide and the count doesn't appear either.

Comment: @LightM1 I made changes in html see http://jsfiddle.net/xYXGX/2/ . I added index attribute to all images and I am using it to show count information. for jsfiddle you can edit after that you can click run to see changes.

Comment: @Shusl it worked! Thanks! You are very clever! I would never thought about the index attribute at all! Thank You. I just learn something new. Thank You. I appreciated you taking your time to help and resolve this issue. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be using this

```
.find('img:first').length;
```

So the count will always be **1** if it has images in it..

Try this instead

```
var count = $slides.closest('.slideshow').find('img').length;
```

Also **this** does not make any senses in the current function context..
Replace it with **$slides**

Comment: @ Sushanth Thanks for the reply and example I will make some adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

The Syntax has to be:

```
var count = $('div.myDiv').find('img').size();
```

so in your case it would be:

```
var count = $(this).closest('.slideshow').find('img').size();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and example I will make some adjustments

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var count = $(".slides > img").size();
```

---

Its better to use `id` and not `class` in your case. so your `div` will look like that:

```
  <div id="slides">
    <img src="image/1a.jpg" width="500" height="500" alt="Caption 1 Image is ..." />
    <img src="image/2a.jpg" width="500" height="500" alt="Caption 2 Image is ..." />
    <img src="image/3a.jpg" width="500" height="500" alt="Caption 3 Image is ..." />
    <img src="image/4a.jpg" width="500" height="500" alt="Caption 4 Image is ..." />
  </div>
...
```

And your jquery code:

```
var count = $("#slides > img").size();
```

see example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/liorlolo/YD28x/2/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply and example. I will make some adjustments